# How to parse date from command line in Solaris?

Tags: shell, date, unix, solaris

```
$uname -a 
SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-33 sun4v sparc sun4v

$date
Friday,  6 May 2016  7:43:41 PM AEST

$ date | cut -d"," -f1
Friday
```

Now I need to cut the date alone where the output is `6 May 2016`

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
date '+%e %B %Y' | cut -b 2-
```

Where [`date`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/date.html)`'+%e %B %Y'` outputs something like " 6 May 2016" and [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/cut.html)`-b 2-` just removes the first byte (space character).

Another way to do it:

```
set "$(date +'%e %B %Y')"
echo "${1# }"
```

Comment: A fork and a pipe to remove a single character? Please do not proliferate this anti-pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Without expensive forks/pipes to cut and whatnot:

```
set $(date)
echo $2 $3 $4
```

Or what about reading the date(1) manual, possibly along with the strftime(3) manual. This will teach you how you can use arbitrary formats that give you exactly the items you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`date | cut -d' ' -f2-4`

which separates by space and takes fields 2-4 (inclusive).

Comment: that fails when you have 2 spaces instead of just 1